# I have created a dice betting game. I cannot get the loop to run correctly could someone help me with finding the issue?

Tags: infinite-loop

Okay so I need help with getting the bank to NOT reset to 100 after each time the loop runs. I have tried many ways but can't seem to get it to work. Could you please help me with a few explanations and examples?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int displaystats(int gamesplayed, int wins, int losses, int bank);

int main()
{
    int bank = 100;//intital bank value
    int bet = 0;//desired wager
    int wins = 0;//games won
    int losses = 0;//games lost
    int gamesplayed = 0;//how many rounds you played
    int compdice1 = 0;//first rolled dice for computer
    int compdice2 = 0;//second rolled dice for computer
    int playdice1 = 0;//first rolled dice for player
    int playdice2 = 0;//seconds rolled dice for player
    int newdice = 0;//the dice to risk your wager
    int comproll = 0;//the sum of the computers roll
    int playroll = 0;//the sum of the players roll

    do
    {
        if (bank < 0)
        {
            cout << "You have " << bank << " coins in your bank." << endl;
            cout << "I am sorry you are out of money." << endl;
            displaystats(gamesplayed, wins, losses, bank);
            break;
        }

        else if (bank > 0)
        {
            cout << "You have " << bank << " coins in your bank." << endl;
            cout << "How many coins would you like to bet? ";
            cin >> bet;

            compdice1 = (rand() + time(0)) % 6 + 1;//computer dice
            compdice2 = (rand() + time(0)) % 6 + 1;//computer second dice
            playdice1 = (rand() + time(0)) % 6 + 1;//player dice
            playdice2 = (rand() + time(0)) % 6 + 1;//player second dice

            comproll = compdice1 + compdice2;//computer sum
            playroll = playdice1 + playdice2;//player sume

            cout << "Your roll was " << playdice1 << " and " << playdice2 << " with a sume of " << playroll << endl;

            if (playroll < comproll)
            {
                char option;//option to roll another dice


                cout << "You win!" << endl;
                cout << "Would you like to roll a third dice to earn 1.5 times your bet, yes or no? ";
                cin >> option;

                if (option == 'yes')
                {
                    int newroll;//the new sum of the three dice
                    int newdice;//the extra roll

                    newdice = (rand() + time(0)) % 6 + 1;
                    newroll = playroll + newdice;//the value of players roll

                    if (newroll > comproll)
                    {
                        cout << "The computer rolled " << comproll << endl;
                        cout << "You now rolled higher than the computer therefore, I am sorry you lose this round." << endl;
                        cout << "Your bank now equals " << bank - bet << endl;
                        losses++;
                        gamesplayed++;
                    }

                    else if (newroll < comproll)
                    {
                        cout << "You win!" << endl;
                        cout << "Your bank now equals " << bank + (1.5 * bet) << endl;
                        wins++;
                        gamesplayed++;
                    }
                }
                else if (option == 'no')
                {
                    cout << "Your bank now equals " << bank + bet << endl;
                    wins++;
                    gamesplayed++;
                }
            }

            else if (playroll > comproll)
            {
                cout << "The computer rolled " << comproll << endl;
                cout << "You rolled higher than the computer therefore, I am sorry you lose this round." << endl;
                cout << "Your bank now equals " << bank - bet << endl;
                losses++;
                gamesplayed++;
            }

            else if (playroll = comproll)
            {
                cout << "The computer also rolled " << comproll << endl;
                cout << "I am sorry you now lose double your bet!" << endl;
                cout << "Your bank now equals " << bank - (2 * bet) << endl;
                losses++;
                gamesplayed++;
            }
        }
    } while (bank > 0);

    int stats = displaystats(gamesplayed, wins, losses, bank);

    cout << "Your stats are " << stats << endl;
    return 0;
}

int displaystats(int gamesplayed, int wins, int losses, int bank)
{
    cout << "Games Played: " << gamesplayed << endl;
    cout << "Wins: " << wins << endl;
    cout << "Losses: " << losses << endl;
    cout << "Bank Total: " << bank << endl;

    return (gamesplayed, wins, losses, bank);
}
```

Comment: If we are going to take the time to answer your question, could you please give more information, and show us the RELEVANT code on stack overflow?

Comment: I have fixed the loop problem. However now I need the bank total to change with every loop and I can't figure out how. Any suggestions?

Comment: Link may get expired and solution may not make sense.

Comment: I tried inserting the code but I did not understand how to do the indenting. I am sorry for the inconvienence could you please still help?

Comment: @agenise1 Try posting the relevant code, select the relevant code, and then hit the appropriate button to mark it as code. (It has the symbol of: {} . ) Just curious... Is this a school project?

Comment: How does that prevent you from adding the code.  Someone else will indent it for you.

Comment: So, we have a question with no code, and the title relates to a problem that has been fixed, and a new problem now exists only referred to in the comments. _Nobody_ should be wasting time on this, and the OP should delete it and start again.

Comment: I am sorry everyone. This is my first post. I am trying to make it better. And I am learning. I have fixed my first problem which should be a good thing...

Comment: But now I need help with just not getting the bank to reset every time. Yes it is a school project but I have done everything and worked on it completely alone except for this one part. Please

Comment: Thank you @Rootix for helping with posting the code.

Comment: @agenise1 Your welcome, typing up an answer atm for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem with the bank "resetting" constantly was you never actually subtracted the bet from the bank. See the following code, I hope this helps.

```
cout << "You have " << bank << " coins in your bank." << endl;
cout << "How many coins would you like to bet? ";
cin >> bet;


//This is the line that you forgot.
bank = bank - bet
```

If you then win, then you may want to later on add some money back into the bank. (But this is up to you.) I hope this helps.

EDIT:

Here is a paste-bin for the full code as requested: http://pastebin.com/HzvRxjXL

Also, if this solves your problem, I would appreciate it if you would mark it as the answer so others don't spend time answering a problem that has been solved.

EDIT 2:

This has a (As far as I can tell) fixed and commentated version of the code. I hope this helps: http://pastebin.com/miQjy4B5

Comment: So I should write this within the loop?

Comment: The relevant line is #42

Comment: The code now repeats really quickly and doesn't start over? Like if I win then it asks if I want to roll a third dice and if I say yes everything just repeats like ten times.

Comment: Ahh wait do I need to add breaks?

Comment: well you have some other bugs in the code that could be doing it. (Your re-roll system could probably use some work.) It appears to be  a school project, and its not ethical to complete your code for you. If you ask about something I will do my best to help you, but its unethical and potentially plagiarism if I do it for you. I hope you understand my predicament.

Comment: of course, i just don't know what you mean by work. Like should I use a switch statement or are the if statements okay?

Comment: what isn't working? This fixes the issue of the bank value not decreasing. You have several bugs in your code, but this should fix the one you asked about. As for the the work for the re-roll, remember... char is only one byte. You are assessing it against several bytes.

Comment: I am just so frustrated. I don't see the bugs in my code, it runs but just doesn't run correctly. I just don't know how to fix the bugs

Comment: Would you be willing to walk me through the problems? I honestly don't want you to give me an answer i would like to learn why and how to fix problems

Comment: Okay okay. I understand the byte thing with char. I fixed that. Its working much better now. Sorry to bombard you.

Comment: @agenise1 its fine. I got a commented, fixed version of the code if you want it. Also, if this answers the question I would appreciate it if you could mark it as the best answer.

Comment: @agenise1 Its under edit 2, but here it is: http://pastebin.com/miQjy4B5 , Also I would appreciate it if you could mark this as the answer if it solves your problem.